# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __gCrWeb

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I have javascript error tracking on my website. Recently I started getting the following error from Chrome (versions 37 and 38) on iPhone (IOS 7 and 8):

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __gCrWeb

I couldn't find any useful information about this error except for a few references. Has anyone seen it before and knows why it happens?

Comment: for me same error. More information: Browser - iPhone Safari 5.0, User agent - Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/38.0.2125.59 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4

Comment: We see it 99% on iPad Chrome. Never get a stack trace. We also have issues with iPad Safari randomly crashing so we worry that this is the culprit.

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/38.0.2125.67 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4

Comment: fwiw, CriOS is Chrome for iOS.

Comment: Just out of curiosity are you using WordPress? I've found this wordpress related article if it helps:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/white-list-error-on-tab6-404

Comment: @wifibrain no wordpress.

Comment: Also see this error via our JavaScript tracking. Is this expected?

Comment: I am using bugsnag on my website and it points to momentjs library as the script that caused the error. Are you also using momentjs?

Comment: @achabacha322 no momentjs

Comment: We are seeing this as well. We do not use momentjs. We are seeing this mainly on Chrome for iPad but also on IE 8. We use wordpress for admin only. Our front end stack is jQuery with Foundation 5 and Foundation 3 for IE 8 (via conditional comments). This is not a wordpress site.

Comment: I use drupal 6 site and errors was expected by newrelic

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`__gcrweb` is a reference by `gcrweb.js`, which is a local (on device) js getting injected by the iOS version of Chrome.

Google needs to do this for some extended functionality (mostly inserting/retrieving login credentials and other form information you stored via another synced Chrome browser) which isn't provided by the native webview it's built on and can't be added to it otherwise.

This should not affect any parts of your code and i'd get rid of it by ignoring it in your error logging (the error should always be the same string), for example:

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/config/

https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar.js/#ignoring-specific-exception-messages

Another solution *could* be to make sure that the reference always exists by declaring it yourself at the beginning of your js init

```
if (!window.__gCrWeb) window['__gCrWeb'] = {};
```

just like [Google does it](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/ios/web/web_state/js/resources/base.js).

Comment: Thanks! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately unable to find something specific after searching for a bit. The rationale for it is at http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/layered-components-design . Neither the script nor it's injection seem to be in the chromium source ( see msg at http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-ios ) but i didn't dig too deep.

Comment: Stand corrected: At least the source is at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/ios/web/web_state/js/

Comment: The main usage seems to be to interact with the page for form handling (add login credentials that you saved on a synced desktop Chrome etc), will update answer: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/ios/web/web_state/js/resources/common.js

Comment: it looks like chrome tries to use this to enable/disable autofill of forms.

Comment: but surely setting it to `{}` will disable google's code leading to unexpected password filling problems

Comment: The workaround `window['__gCrWeb'] = {};` will not work, if  there are errors on next level, e.g. `undefined is not an object (evaluating '__gCrWeb.instantSearch.clearHighlight')`