# null is not an object (evaluating '__gCrWeb.form.wasEditedByUser.set')

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome

I keep getting an error in my angular app of

`null is not an object (evaluating '__gCrWeb.form.wasEditedByUser.set')`

in my rollbar error logs

It's only on chrome ios, and I believe it's something to do with autofill but I've not been able to replicate the error.

Just wondering if it's safe to ignore

Comment: was reported on our app as well. Apparently it prevents people from submitting the form

Comment: @rzr any ideas on what causes it?

Comment: Also having this issue, also only on Chrome on iOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: \_\_gCrWeb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483541/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-gcrweb)

Answer (score 0):

It happens in Chrome on iOS. There are many issues related to gCrWeb such as this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=590375) about chromium and [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483541/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-gcrweb). It is also referenced in this [chromium discussion thread](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/ead0c0104c5e297be93a5aaaf0c11870ae15b1d0%5E%21/). It seems to me you got nothing to worry about.